# For Loop in C does not work as Expected

Tags: c, for-loop

I don't understand the flow of the following `for` loop: it becomes an infinite loop. I am using ubuntu 12.04. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int k,a[10];
    for(k=0; k<=10; k++)
    {
        a[k]=1;
        printf("k = %d\n",k);
    }
}
```

Once `k == 9`, it automatically changes to `1`. I don't know why it behaves like this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're accessing the array out of bounds so you have undefined behaviour. You should fix that first.

Comment: Also, if for some reason k is directly after a in memory then you'd certainly get an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, your code isn't valid C++. You need to specify the return type of `main`, which is `int`.

Comment: This Loop is running for 11 times,  make it `;k<10;` to make it run 10 times and it should run fine! Problem is you have array of `a[10]` and this loop is calling `a[10] ` that is illegal reference it should call till `a[9]` only , that makes may make it behave like that!

Comment: Let delete out comments to make this post cleared

Comment: @juanchopanza  Wouldn't default type of `main` be considered as `int ` ?

Comment: Hey, I didn't check the condition using array subscript. Instead of I checking the condition using variable. My question is how the value stored in the variable gets changed?

Comment: @ameyCU C++ doesn't have default types. C doesn't, since C99 IIRC, maybe even earlier.

Comment: The implicit return type has been bad style since before C89 was ratified and should never be used in new code.  And by "new code" here, I mean any code written after 1987.  Turn up your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5):

```
 for(k=0; k<=10; k++)
```

This access out of bound index . `a[10]`(indexing start with `0` therefore valid index `0-9`) is out of bound and invoke **undefined behaviour**.

loop should be this -

```
 for(k=0; k<10; k++)
```

Comment: Ok. I didn't check the condition as a[k]<=10. I check the variable only. So,  how k value is changed one it reaches 9.

Comment: @mohan  Your code's behaviour is undefined . So only conclusion I could make is that it could give anything .

Comment: @mohan Probably because `i` happened to be stored just after the array in the stack. This may not always be the case, though. It is UB.

Comment: @mohan Sorry. Not `i`, but `k`. ^

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system doesn't affect the way the loop is processed. What you need is a way to handle the integer variable "k" and inside the loop, you need to make "k" greater than 10 for the loop to exit properly. So I made K increment so that each element of the integer array "a" contains the value 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int k,a[11];
for(k=0; k<=10; k++)
{
    a[k]=1;
    printf("k = %d\n",k);
    k++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually array index starts from 0. So if you have an array "a" with 10 members in it, then the members will be

1st member - a[0];
2nd member - a[1]; 3rd member - a[2]; ... ... ... 10th member - a[9]

So, you can't have a member a[10]. But in your for loop you started k from 0 and incremented it to 10. But a[10] was not present in the array and this caused the infinite loop. To solve this problem, just use **"k<10"** as your loop condition. Your code should look like this now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int k,a[10];
    for(k=0; k<10; k++)
    {
        a[k]=1;
        printf("k = %d\n",k);
    }
}
```

The reason k is becoming 1 after 9 is that for some reason k is situated right after the memory range of a. So, when you change a[10] to 1, it actually changes the value of k. So, you get 1 as the value of k.